# Class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] not found

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jdbc, vaadin

I try to test Vaadin JPAContainer demo 'jpacontainer-addressbook-demo' to connect to oracle. But I met exception.

```
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] not found.
```

My persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="oracle">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have put ojdbc6.jar to WEB-INF/lib. And I cound found ojdbc6.jar in WEB-INF\lib\ of jpacontainer-addressbook-demo-3.2.0.war. I dont understand why it have this exception. Any hints would be much appreciated.

I found the solution by following this page.
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

But I dont know why cant just directly put jar file to lib folder. Could any one help to explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration hints towards the driver not being loaded because of a configuration error.
Depending on your appserver you might have to change the database url.

We use Wildfly and Weblogic and there the URL uses a slash between server and database names:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl

And according to a post on the [OTN](https://community.oracle.com/message/10423207#10423207) it would be again different for Glassfish:
jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521:orcl

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you

If you are using Eclipse then you can just include this JAR in your build path by selecting project, right click, properties, Java Build path and then adding JAR on libraries tab.